# Substituir WebForms por MVC

Tags: webforms

Há como ou alguma ferramenta, apenas para evitar a reescrita, de substituir um código desenvolvido em WebForms e transportá-lo para MVC? No WebForms existe os *runat=server*, *user control*, *asp: Label* e etc... Exemplo de parte do código a ser substituídos:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scpManager" runat="server" OnPreRender="scpManager_PreRender">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" BackColor="#E1EBF2" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt"
                ForeColor="#666666" Text="CNPJ: " Style="margin-left: 10px;"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtCnpj" runat="server" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdPesquisar" runat="server" OnClick="cmdPesquisar_Click"
                Text="Pesquisar" Width="106px" Style="margin-left: 10px;" />
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div style="position: absolute; width: 99%; height: 99%; z-index: 1;">
                        <br />
                        <asp:Image ID="imgCarregando" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Carregando.gif"
                            Style="position: absolute; top: -27px; left: 393px; height: 32px;" Width="32px" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAtualiza" Style="position: absolute; top: -17px; left: 440px;" runat="server" Font-Size="12pt" ForeColor="#6D7CA3" Text="Pesquisando..."></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, não existe nenhuma ferramenta para isso.

A maior – e praticamente única – camada à ser alterada para fazer essa [portabilidade](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/portabilidade/) é a de apresentação – no MVC, a famosa *"view"* – e não há nada que vá automatizar o processo para você: *você realmente precisa fazer "no braço".*

Se você tem pressa e não tem muitas opções, o conselho que eu posso te dar para minimizar *um pouco* o seu percurso, é utilizar um [Chrome Developer's Tool](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) da vida para resgatar o HTML gerado das suas páginas e salvá-los em arquivos ".cshtml". *Lembrando, se você insistir nessa "técnica", seja atencioso com os JavaScripts e outras dependências necessárias; além disso, vale lembrar que o código gerado pelo WebForms para apresentações não estão totalmente de acordo com as normas da W3C.*

Comment: Alias acho que não só o html terá que ser refeito mas muito código mesmo, afinal não se trabalha mais com webcontrols nativos do .net e sim com html controls normais.

Comment: Eu já esperava por isso. O trampo que não queremos é o que teremos que fazer.